# I want to start learning Demandware

Tags: demandware

Is there a website or tutorial to have a "Hello World" and more for demandware?

Where can I find the demand ware api documentation

Is there someway to have free server access, for training purpose ?

I already installed Eclipse and UX plugin..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648740/demandware-technology-stack

Answer (score 15):

The main resources for such queries would be

- https://xchange.demandware.com/community/developer
- https://documentation.demandware.com

Both require that you have a valid Demandware XChange account.
It should be possible to request such by Demandware support.

There is no free server access as far as I am aware. To get a sandbox, you need to have an active subscription for Demandware SaaS.
It may be the case that your employer/client already has one, so it may be good to check with them.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pay-to-play kind of model, so you can't really learn it without having an enterprise account with DW.  If you do have one, you can get access to xchange where there are lots of training videos and documents....but basically it's just like NodeJS with some DW-specific calls and some, optional, funky flow chart things.